# How to change integral bounds when calculating an improper integral

Tags: integration, statistics, improper-integrals, change-of-variable

So it is estabilished that for definite integrals, the following holds:
$$\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)du$$
given
$ u=g(x)$.
However, when calculating the expectation of a standard normal distribution I have noticed that the bounds BOTH get mapped to $-\infty$, given $u={-1 \over 2}x^2$: $$ 0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-{1\over2} x^2} =\int_{-g(\infty)}^{g(\infty)} -e^{u} du = \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} -e^{u} du  = -|e^u|_{-\infty}^{-\infty} = -|0-0| =0$$

I feel like the fact that this result is correct is a pure coincidence. For me it doesn't really make sense to integrate over an "infinitely negative point", especially if the range of values of $u$ is $(-\infty, 0]$, so I would expect the whole range to be covered by the integral, while only $-\infty$ is covered.

Can someone provide an answer if this is generally correct or not, if not, is it even possible to change the integration bounds when I have an improper integral, or should I just use an indefinite integral and convert back to the original variable?

Comment: It works for improper integrals as well, as limits of definite ones. The fact that this result is correct is *not* "a pure coincidence".

Comment: When you transform variables by $u=g(x)$ in integrals, then $g$ need not be injective. It can map both bounds to the same value and run through the interval as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can part the domain at $x=0$, so

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm d x &= \int_{-\infty}^0 x\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm d x+ \int^{\infty}_0 x\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm d x\\&~~\vdots\\ &= (1-0)+(0-1)\end{align}$$